# Have 3 cells calculate each other while avoiding circular reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

**Hello I believe I ran into Excel's limitations (or at least mine)...**

Simple scenario: I want to visualize mathematical relation of values. Lets assume I have three fields: Year / Month / Days

All fields are '0 (or empty)' at the beginning. If I enter '2' for years I want month to update to 24 and days to 730. If I now choose to enter 36 for month I want the years to update to 3 and the days to update to 1095. This is just an example I need this to calculate coin volumes held by different containers.

Using IF conditions I managed to make this scenario possible for at least one data entry / afterwards I obviously lost the formula of the field I overwrote with my data. My approach also caused a circular reference.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't, not with formulas. A cell can either hold a formula or a constant, not both. If you enter a value into a cell, any formula will be overwritten.

If all three cells contain formulas, there's no way to get an actual value to be calculated into the circuit.

And, of course, if the cells reference each other, then that is the very definition of a circular reference.

If you want to avoid the dilemma, use VBA to watch the three cells, do the calculation in VBA and write the result into the respective other two cells.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with only three cells (not with formulas), but you can do that with three input cells and three output cells (days/months/year in each case). Each of the output cells will then contain a formula that uses the one input cell that is not empty to calculate the number of days/months/years.

You will, however, need to check that at least two of the three input cells are empty.